# Unable to split an IP address

Tags: powershell

I am trying to collect an IP Address and then split that IP address however I keep getting an error message.

```
$Hostname = hostname
$IPAddress = Test-Connection $Hostname -Count 1 | Select IPV4ADDRESS | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
$IPAddress2 = $IPAddress.Split('.')
```

Error Message: Method invocation failed because

> [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData] does
>   not contain a method named 'Split'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that

```
(Test-Connection $hostname -Count 1).IPV4Address.GetAddressBytes() | 
    % { $_.ToString() }
```

The output of the `Format-XXX` cmdlets is not intended being used as strings etc. as this are formatting commands for the console

Comment: This is pretty cool Dax I have never seen the gathering of terms be used like that before. (Test-Connection $hostname -Count 1).IPV4Address.GetAddressBytes() Really great stuff

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `Format-*` cmdlets unless you actually need to format output

Instead, do:

```
$IPAddress = Test-Connection $Hostname -Count 1 | Select -Expand IPV4Address
$IPAddress2 = $IPAddress.IPAddressToString.Split('.')
```

Comment: Good point I thought it might be causing part of the problem. However when I removed it I just got another error message which lead me to believe that there is a second problem with that part of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Remove Format-Table. Format commands are for displaying output, not for when you expect to work with the thing you've pulled back.

```
$Hostname = hostname
$Ping = Test-Connection $Hostname -Count 1
$IPAddress = $Ping.IPv4Address.IPAddressToString.Split('.')
```